# FFmpeg plus the - c:v copy parameter - force_ key_ Frames won't work?

Tags: ffmpeg

I understand that the -force_key_frames parameter is to insert key frames into the video

Because the generated ts fragment is very different from the specified -hls_time parameter, the -force_key_frame parameter is added. I have 20T video resources. In order to speed up the encoding time, I chose -c:v copy not to encode, but this -force_key_frames has no effect. Is there any way to make TS fragments accurate without sacrificing coding time and ensuring image quality and storage space。

I have tried NVENC coding, but the image quality is too poor. In order to achieve the image quality of -crf 23 level, it needs more storage space than the original file

Thank you for your advice

I tried -c:v copy -f segment -segment_time parameter, we have also tried nvenc coding -preset p7 -cq 20 and libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 23.

Although nvenc is fast, it sacrifices image quality and storage space. Although libx264 improves image quality and storage space, it may be next year to transcode 20T video

Comment: There is a `-break_non_keyframes` option "allow breaking segments on non-keyframes (default false)". `-force_key_frames` has no effect without re-encoding. Split segments to non constant times is also an option. If no option is good enough then just wait a year (probably just a month).

Comment: It is not work to use hls related parameters, but segment related parameters are OK. Thank you very much